# Bash Unix Shell Script to Accept Input and Set System Variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to modify an existing shell script to accept user input and handle some system exports. The below is an excerpt from a larger script.  After running this script, I echo $TEST_DIR and I don't get anything back.  Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$TEST_DIR" ]
then
    echo "TEST_DIR was not set, please enter the path: "
    read input_variable
    export TEST_DIR=$input_variable
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Try `source ‘filename’`.

Comment: You are exiting from this so it seems you are calling this in a child shell and that must be the reason why the variable is not visible. How are you invoking it? Invoke it in the existing shell i.e. by prefixing is with . i.e. instead of using myScript use . myScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save this as `script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$TEST_DIR" ]
then
    echo "TEST_DIR was not set, please enter the path: "
    read input_variable
    export TEST_DIR=$input_variable
fi
```

And run it like this:

```
. ./script.sh
```

Or, equivalently:

```
source ./script.sh
```

`source` runs the script in the current environment and consequently lets you modify the environment in the script. Without it every command, which runs as a child of the shell process, is only given a copy of the current environment.

Note I removed the `exit` line, as it would terminate the shell in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running the script in a subshell - it's setting your `TEST_DIR` properly, but then the shell exits, and the parent shell doesn't keep the change.

You might be better off making this a function you can source from the parent shell. Shell scripts can't modify the environment of the calling shell, but a function can modify the shell it's executing in.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do `exit 1`; that is used to indicate failure.  You'd use `exit 0` to indicate success — but, as described below, you don't want to do that, either, in this case.

The other problem is that if you run the script as child process, it cannot affect the environment of the parent process.

To work around that, in POSIX shells, you need to use:

```
. your_script.sh
```

or, in `bash`, you can also use:

```
source your_script.sh
```

The script does not have to be executable, just readable, and will be searched for on `$PATH` unless you specify a name containing a slash, just like other commands.

And, when you do the `.` or `source`, you definitely do not want any `exit` in the script because that will cause the main shell to exit.  The shell reads the file as if you were typing it at standard input (more or less), so an `exit` that's executed will exit the shell.